# why fragment.onCreate are called after activity.onStart instead of activity.onCreate

Tags: android, android-fragments

the background is an Activity includes a Fragment:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        Log.d("===Activity: ","onCreate")
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            supportFragmentManager.commit {
                add(R.id.main_cv, MainFragment())
                setReorderingAllowed(true)
                addToBackStack(null)
            }
        }
    }
```

then i use some logs to observe the order of these lifecycle callbacks,the result is as follows:

```
===Activity:: onCreate
===Activity:: onStart
===Fragment:: onAttach
===Fragment:: onCreate
===Fragment:: onCreateView
===Fragment:: onViewCreated
===Fragment:: onStart
```

i dont know why fragment.onCreate are called after activity.onStart instead of activity.onCreate.
**Activity:**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        Log.d("===Activity: ","onCreate")
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            supportFragmentManager.commit {
                add(R.id.main_cv, MainFragment())
                setReorderingAllowed(true)
                addToBackStack(null)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        Log.d("===Activity: ","onStart")
        super.onStart()
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        Log.d("===Activity: ","onResume")
        super.onResume()
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        Log.d("===Activity: ","onPause")
        super.onPause()
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        Log.d("===Activity: ","onStop")
        super.onStop()
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        Log.d("===Activity: ","onDestroy")
        super.onDestroy()
    }
}
```

**Fragment:**

```
class MainFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        Log.d("===Fragment: ","onAttach")
        super.onAttach(context)
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        Log.d("===Fragment: ","onCreate")
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        Log.d("===Fragment: ","onCreateView")
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        Log.d("===Fragment: ","onViewCreated")
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        Log.d("===Fragment: ","onStart")
        super.onStart()
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        Log.d("===Fragment: ","onResume")
        super.onResume()
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        Log.d("===Fragment: ","onPause")
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        Log.d("===Fragment: ","onStop")
        
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        Log.d("===Fragment: ","onDestroyView")
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        Log.d("===Fragment: ","onDestroy")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an `Activity` is created it goes through the following stages :

1. **`onCreate()`**
2. **`onStart()`**
3. **`onResume()`**

When a `Fragment` is added to the `Activity`, it goes through the following stages:

1. **`onAttach()`**
2. **`onCreate()`**
3. **`onCreateView()`**
4. **`onViewCreated()`**
5. **`onActivityCreated()`**
6. **`onStart()`**
7. **`onResume()`**

> why fragment.onCreate are called after activity.onStart instead of activity.onCreate

To answer your question, the reason why `onCreate()` of a `Fragment` is called after `onStart()` of its parent `Activity` is because `Fragments` are a part of the `Activity` lifecycle, and their lifecycle methods are called after the corresponding `Activity` lifecycle methods.

As you can see, the `onCreate()` method of a `Fragment` is called after the `onStart()` method of its parent `Activity`. This is because `onStart()` is called when the `Activity` becomes visible to the user, and it's only after this point that the `Fragment` can be added to the `Activity` and its `onCreate()` method can be called.

To understand it better here's an image

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. Now i am clear that fragment are added after the time when Activity is visible(after activity.onstart()). But the bottom image seems to indicate that fragment.onAttach()...fragment.onActivityCreated() are called after activity.onCreate().

Comment: As I can see on the diagram, the `onCreate()` method of a Fragment is called **before**, not after, the `onStart()` method of its parent Activity.

Answer (score 0):

The Activity **onStart()** method indicates that the activity is now going to be **visible** but may be not in the **foreground** and may be obscured by other activity.

When activity completes **onStart()** method then it indicates as the activity is visible and now it can perform any **attachments** of the fragments or views.

So after **onStart()** method fragments method will gets invoked.

I hope this makes sense to your question and the right one which you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now i know that activity can perform attachment of fragment only after it is visible.